# Jbutton does not start class activity by first click

Tags: java, swing, jbutton

I have to press twice on a button to start a Jchooser:

I have a Handler Class:

```
package tekstapplicatie;

    import java.awt.event.*;
    import java.io.*;

    public class Handler implements ActionListener {

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0)
        {
                Scherm.openen.addActionListener( new Lezen() );
                System.out.println( "Fout bij het lezen of sluiten bestand" );

                Scherm.opslaanals.addActionListener( new Opslaanals() );
            }
        }
```

When I press the button Scherm.openen, the message is for debug purposes is shown so my buttons works.
However the next piece of code does not start.
It only starts when I press the button one more time. 
The message is not shown the second time when i press the button).

```
package tekstapplicatie;

import java.awt.event.*;
import java.io.*;

import javax.swing.JFileChooser;
import javax.swing.filechooser.FileNameExtensionFilter;

public class Lezen implements ActionListener 
{
    public void actionPerformed( ActionEvent arg )
    {
//      BufferedReader in;
//        String regel;    

        JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser();
        FileNameExtensionFilter filter = new FileNameExtensionFilter(
            "TXT & GIF Images", "txt", "gif");
        chooser.setFileFilter(filter);
        int returnVal = chooser.showOpenDialog(null);
        if(returnVal == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
           System.out.println("You chose to open this file: " +
                chooser.getSelectedFile().getName());
           Scherm.gekozenbestand = chooser.getSelectedFile().getName();
           Scherm.absoluutpad = chooser.getSelectedFile().getAbsolutePath();
        }

        String path = Scherm.absoluutpad; 
        System.out.println(path);

    try {
            Scherm.in = new BufferedReader( new FileReader( Scherm.absoluutpad ) );

        while ( ( Scherm.regel = Scherm.in.readLine() ) != null ) 
        {
        System.out.println( Scherm.regel );
        System.out.println( Scherm.absoluutpad);
        Scherm.tekstveld.append(Scherm.regel);
        Scherm.tekstveld.setCaretPosition(Scherm.tekstveld.getDocument().getLength());
        }
      Scherm.in.close();
    }
    catch( FileNotFoundException f ) {
      System.out.println( "Kan bestand niet vinden" );
    }
    catch( IOException i ) {
      System.out.println( "Fout bij het lezen of sluiten bestand" );
      i.printStackTrace();
    }
}
}
```

What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: `(the message is not shown for the second time).` you mean 1st time? BTW, from your snippets of code I don't see any problem. Sounds like the issue is on other part

Comment: Should not you add the line 'Scherm.openen.addActionListener( new Lezen() );' before pressing the button, instead of adding it when you press the button the first time?

Comment: @skandigraun yes, good point, Plumbum7 please, iniitate listeners on application start